# Kickstarting RHEL7 VM stalls with "No device selected"

Tags: kvm-virtualization, kickstart, rhel7

I've been using [Ashgar Ghori's RHEL7 study guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1495148203) and have hit a small snag which I have not been able to find a solution to.

Using a kickstart file that worked previously, whenever I use it for a new server I am taken to the Installation Summary screen which indicates `No device selected` under the `Installation Destination` section.

I've searched for a solution but even Red Hat doesn't have anything that helps. There is one article in their knowledgebase that provides some troubleshooting, but the generic kickstart file they provide to test with does the same thing.

I've recreated the volume I'm trying to use. I've selected different volumes. I've modified the kickstart file format. Nothing works.

[This is my kickstart file.](http://pastebin.com/1QJMKFFS)

*EDIT:* The details say "Specified upartitioned disk vda in partition command"

Answer (score 0):

When I created the kickstart file I had the `clearpart` directive uncommented. It failed but I did not think to look at the details so I don't know why. The [Red Hat knowledgebase article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1296133) omitted this directive so I commented it out. The issue persisted.

That said, now that it is again uncommented and allowed to be executed as part of the kickstart it is working. So, since I didn't look at the details when I first encountered this error I don't know what the problem originally was.

Comment: It was probably unrelated to the `clearpart` command. You can easily get this error if your VM is wrongly configured in some way, e.g. when the destination disk device (you use in your kickstart config) is much too small, is missing or named differently.